# Is it possible to use the infoVis JIT plugin within Grails 2.3.6?

Tags: grails, plugins, jit, infovis

I am having dificulties integrating the [jit-plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jit) into my Grails 2.0.7 project. The Documentation that comes with the Plugin unfortunately does not provide enough information for me to understand how to integrate the plugin into mey GSP. The example links are all dead as well. 
Is anybody aware of a place for me to find an example GSP for the jit-plugin or can provide me with one? 
Or is it even possible to make the plugin work with Grails 2.3.6?

Here is an extract from my buildConfig.groovy

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
}

dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    compile: ":jit:0.2:"
}

plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.50.1"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.1'
    compile ":pure-css:0.4.2"
    compile: ":jit:0.2:"


    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.8" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.1.1"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.0"
    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

    // An alternative to the default resources plugin is the asset-pipeline plugin
    //compile ":asset-pipeline:1.5.0"

    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.5.1"
    //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.5.0"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.5.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.0.0.3"
}
```

Thanks in advance. 
Chris

Comment: The links to the documentation and examples from the plugin page work just fine. What's the issue?

Comment: In the google docs documentation file there are links to the source gsp-files. Those don't work. And that's exactly what I actually needed. I edited the my BuildConfig.groovy in the original post. I suspect that might be the issue.

Comment: Here is where the documentation link, that I needed leads me: http://www.odelia-technologies.com/files/spacetree.gsp

Comment: Add compile: ":jit:0.2:" to the plugin closure not the dependencies closure.

Comment: I tried that already. Then I found, that it says to add it to the dependency closure on the plugin page. Either way, when I include the <jit:resources id="infoVis" var="iv" data="${outMap}"/>-tag in the head section of my gsp, it tells me it doesn't recognize the tag. Furthermore, when running the app, the console never said anything about downloading the plugin. It doesn't come up with errors as well.

Comment: Since the GSP links are broken/missing your best bet is going to be to open up the source for the plugin and look at the taglibs and see how they are written and how you can use them.

Comment: And how do I get the plugin's source code?

Comment: In a 2.0.7 project any installed plugin should have it's source code at: %USERHOME%\.grails\2.0.7\projects\%PROJECTNAME%\plugins

Comment: It's a 2.3.6 project. I mistakenly put the groovy version. I'm sorry. I corrected it. The Plugins directory doesn't have the jit plugin. That's what I ment earlyer. It does not even install the plugin from the BuildConfig

Comment: Do a grails clean, grails refresh-dependencies, and grails compile That should force it to download.

Comment: Nope. Still did not install anything. I'm using the grails plugin for eclipse ide by the way. If that is of any interest. Tried to do the clean, refresh-dependencies and compile in console, too though.

Comment: ok. had a typo in the build-config. now it installed it but I still can't see it in the plugins-foler in my project..